# How to interact an across panel unit in fixed effect model?

Tags: interaction, fixed-effects-model

I want to use fixed effect model but I want to test an interaction between female(1 if true) which is not changing across users(id). I wrote Stata code shown below and the results are shown after.

IS it correct to do such cross level interaction in a fixed effect model.
IF it is significant, how can I interpret the results?

Many thanks if anyone can help.

DV: wage IV: working experience, working weeks, and whether is a female.
xtset id t
xtreg lwage experience weeks i.female#c.experience, fe

The results is shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine. I guess you meant to say that female does not vary across time, $t$, not across users, $id$. Because your experience varies across time, the new variable, $1.female*c.experience$ will not be dropped. The interpretation is standard for an interaction of a continuous and binary variable. The effect of a 1-year increase in experience on wages is 0.48% lower for women compared to men.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed illustration. It helps a lot! Now I am confident about using such interaction terms.